# error C2660 : Hiding methods in a derived class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, derived

**Goal:**

Sharing a base class with the same functionality except only a few descendants which merely hides methods (getters and setters) as they instantiate and free a protected or private pointer.

---

**Problem:**

When re-declaring the setter only I get this error when invoking the getter.

```
1>c:\projectengine\problem\main.cpp(8): error C2660: 'cDerived::SomeClass'
    : function does not take 0 arguments
```

The getter isn't really needed but why disclose functionality if it's there already.

---

**Conclusion:**

`cBase::SomeClass()` is untouched by `cDerived`.

When commenting out the next line, no compile error (of course):

```
virtual void        SomeClass( cSomeClass* value ) override {}; // setter, C2660
```

However that would work, and thus not changing anything, there rises a risk for a memory leak. On the other hand, this accidental derivative should inherited the rest of the functionality of `cBase` which is a descendant by itself.

Should I rewrite `cBase` or is it possible to hide only the setter in `cDerived`?

---

The code with the error:

main.cpp

```
class cSomeClass 
{ 
}; 

class cBase : public cAbsoluteBase
{ 
public: 
    cBase() : m_pSomeClass( 0 ){} 
    virtual cSomeClass* SomeClass(){ return m_pSomeClass; } 
    virtual void        SomeClass( cSomeClass* value ){ m_pSomeClass = value; }; 
protected: 
    cSomeClass* m_pSomeClass; 
}; 

class cDerived : public cBase 
{ 
private: 
    //          hide these 
    //virtual cSomeClass* SomeClass() override { return m_pSomeClass; }; 
    virtual void        SomeClass( cSomeClass* value ) override {};
}; 

cDerived derived; 

int main()
{

    cSomeClass* someClass = derived.SomeClass(); // C2660 

    return 0; 

}
```

Comment: [Why is it voted down? : link to meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142378/somehow-i-am-doing-something-wrong)

Comment: Right, overdone it. Have edited.

Comment: Again, I have no idea what you're trying to ask. Ask a question.

Comment: Why do I get the compile error when I call a public function declared at the cBase. But an answer is given and accepted so don't worry, problem has been solved. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You need a [using](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fusing_declaration_class_members.htm) declaration. Otherwise, overloads in the derived class hide the functions in the base class. (Because usually this is an error. If you had to specialize one overload, usually you have to specialize all of them.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I could follow your description accurately, but from the code snippets, it looks like you want to publicly inherit from a class, but remove one of the methods of the base classes interface.

That is possible, it is even possible to do accidentally, but it is a very bad idea™. Public inheritance is an “is-a” relationship. If you have a class `B` publicly inheriting from class `A`, then what declaring that relationship means is “objects of type `B` may be larger than those of type `A`, but apart from that, you can use a `B` wherever an `A` is expected.” Obviously `B`s may have additional behavior, but public inheritance promises that they work as fully functional `A`s. (This is known as the “Liskov Substitution Principle,” by the way.)

Note that this is also why one of the early textbook examples for inheritance was utterly broken: Having `Square` inherit from `Rectangle`. Yes, a square is a rectangle, but that doesn't mean it is sound OO design to have `Square` publicly inherit from `Rectangle`. Because sub-classes having additional restrictions over their parent classes breaks a lot of otherwise perfectly valid and useful code, by not adhering to the established interface contract. (In the case of squares, they break the contract clause that you should be able to change the sides of a rectangle independently from one another. In your case, you seem to be removing parts of the interface altogether.)

Comment: Is it really that unclear? Hope it's better now. You answered indeed the question.

Comment: So a solution could be to move the setter to the other classes with the 'normal' functionality wich leave cBase and thus cDerived with only a getter?

Comment: Yes. Do not remove functionality from an interface. (It is perfectly acceptable and usually much better than deeply nested inheritance trees, to have some abstract base class for the additional interface and use multiple inheritance. There are problems with multiple inheritance, but they do not really apply to the case where you only have one non-empty, non-abstract parent.)

Comment: Changed the acceptance to this later answer due to giving an answer that not only gives a solution that works but an explanation too so I can determine what I should do.